# Can't I access my router after using the Tor Browser!

Tags: routers

Since I've been using the Tor Browser, I am unable to access my router at http://192.168.1.254.  Is this merely a coincidence or an unfortunate side effect of using the Tor Browser.  I'd like to avoid doing a "factory reset" to access my router.  Any suggestions?

Comment: my router ports were closed and i cannot re open even after deleting the TOR file and pc's on this lan use designated ports and it is closed and can not reconfigure ... i did not find an uninstall so i deleted the files and still can not have access to my router

Answer (score 2):

When you access a site via the Tor Browser it sends you traffic through different servers to ensure your anonymity. This means that you cannot access any computers on your local network - including your router as it tries to send the data via Tor. 
To fix this simply use another browser for accessing your local network.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tor to access your router.

In Tor go to Options > Advanced > Network > Settings, at "No proxy for:" you should add the local address of your router.

The Tor proxy will just ignore your router address, and you will connect direct to it only.